# Dask dataframe.read_csv not work correctly with hdfs csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hdfs, dask

I want read csv data from hdfs server, but it throws an Exception,like below:

```
    hdfsSeek(desiredPos=64000000): FSDataInputStream#seek error:
    java.io.EOFException: Cannot seek after EOF
    at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.seek(DFSInputStream.java:1602)
    at 
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:65)
```

**My Python code:**

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('hdfs://SER/htmpa/a.csv').head(n=3)
```

**csv file:**

```
    user_id,item_id,play_count
    0,0,500
    0,1,3
    0,3,1
    1,0,4
    1,3,1
    2,0,1
    2,1,1
    2,3,5
    3,0,1
    3,3,4
    4,1,1
    4,2,8
    4,3,4
```

Comment: What hdfs driver library are you using? I recommend using pyarrow instead of hdfs3 - you can do this by specifying `driver='pyarrow'` to the `read_csv` call.

Comment: "specifying driver='pyarrow' " not work. still throw  seek error

Answer (score 1):

Are you running within and IDE or a jupyter notebook?
We are running on a Cloudera distribution and also get a similar error. From what we understand it is not connected to `dask` but rather to our `hadoop` configuration.
In any case we successfully use the [pyarrow](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/)  library when accessing `hdfs`. be aware that if you need to access `parquet` files run with version `0.12` and not `0.13` [see discussion on github](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/2213)
**Update**
pyarrow version `0.14` is out and should solve the problem.

Comment: ths.pyarrow is work. But a lot code work by dask,:(.